# Use enum as generic type of my class but failed to create instance

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have Enum:

```
public enum MyTypes {FOO, BAR}
```

I defined a class with generic types:

```
public MyClass<T extends MyTypes> {
  private T theType;
  ...
}
```

Above code compiles successfully.

Next, I try to create an instance of MyClass with type Foo as the generic parameter:

```
// Compilation error: Cannot resolve symbol FOO
MyClass<FOO> myInstanceWithFoo = new MyClass();
```

Is it because Java don't accept `enum` type as generic type? If so, is there a workaround to achieve what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because Java don't accept enum type as generic type?

Any enum type is a valid type and can participate in both forming a type parameter (e.g. `MyClass<T extends MyTypes>`) and parameterizing a type (e.g. `MyClass<MyTypes> myInstance`).

What you did

```
MyClass<FOO> myInstanceWithFoo = new MyClass();
```

is never corrent since `FOO` is an instance (or object) of `MyTypes`. It's not a type, and can't be treated as such.

> If so, is there a workaround to achieve what I want to achieve?

There is no need for `MyClass` to be generic. It declares a `MyTypes` field which could be either `MyTypes.FOO` or `MyTypes.BAR` (or `null`, of course).

```
class MyClass {
  private MyTypes myType;

  public MyClass(MyTypes myType) {
    this.myType = myType;
  }
}
```

Each `MyTypes` instance knows how to create a `MyClass` from itself.

```
enum MyTypes {
  FOO, BAR;

  public MyClass createMyClass() {
    return new MyClass(this);
  }
}
```

An example of how to create them would be

```
class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myInstanceWithFoo = MyTypes.FOO.createMyClass();
    MyClass myInstanceWithBar = MyTypes.BAR.createMyClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. On top of your answer, what if `MyTypes` is from 3rd party library that I can't modify to add the `createMyClass()` function there?

Comment: @Leem.fin then init them directly: `new MyClass(MyTypes.FOO)`

Comment: @Leem.fin any reason why you unaccepted? is there anything I can improve?

Answer (score 0):

It's my guess that you're confusing FOO as a subtype as MyClass when it is in fact an instance.

With 'normal' generics you specify the type the placeholder will be:

```
public class GenericClass <T extends Object> { // a bit contrived here
    private T generic;
}
```

which is instantiated

`GenericClass<String> gen = new GenericClass<>(); // String is a subclass of Object`

this is then compiled to

```
public class GenericClass {
   private String generic;
}
```

Notice there is no value for the String. There is no String instance. 
To do this we either need a setter or constructor:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends Object> {
    private T generic;

    public GenericClass(T generic) {
        this.generic = generic;
    }

}

GenericClass<String> gen = new GenericClass<>("Passing in a String because T was a String");
```

or

```
GenericClass<Integer> gen2 = new GenericClass<>(2); // T is integer so we can only pass integers - 2 will be the instance.
```

So for the Enum as a generic type we're stating the type which is MyType. The value would be FOO, so again we'd need either a setter or a constructor:

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyTypes> {
    private T theType;

    public MyClass(T theType) {
        this.theType = theType;
    }

}
```

and to make sure we're have a FOO instance we pass it in to the constructor

```
MyClass<MyTypes> myInstanceWithFoo = new MyClass<>(MyTypes.FOO);
```

Hope this makes sense.